# How can I pass a parameter from the controller index function to the model's functions? LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, api, eloquent, backend

//------------------------------//
//below is the controller index function code //
//------------------------------//

```
public function index($from, $to,$id)
    {
         $data=Attendance::where('attendance_date','>=',$from)
         ->where('attendance_date','<=',$to)
         ->with('userAttendance')//--> **I need to pass the $id to this function in the model**
         ->with('admin')
        ->get()
```

//---------------------------------//
//below is the model code //
//----------------------------------//

```
class Attendance extends Model
{
    protected $table = "attendances";
    protected $fillable=[
        'attendance_date',
        'admin_id',
    ];
                                       //---> **i need the $id passed to here**
    public function userAttendance()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_attendances','attendance_id','user_id')
       ->withPivot(
        'present_absent',
        'excuse',
        'attendance_key_amount',
        'verified_date',
        'comment',
       );
    }
}
```

Comment: what you want to pass and why? please share some more logic.

Comment: I am receiving  in the controller several variables from my route, one of them called `$id` so I need to pass this `$id` to a function named **userAttendance** in the **model** that I am using **Attendance**. I have already called this function in the controller index using eloquent `->with(userAttendance)`, so how can I pass the `$id` variable from the **controller** to this **function in the model**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just try this

Controller:

```
 public function index()
    {
        $id = 50;
        Product::getId(50);
    }
```

Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    public static function getId($id){
        dd($id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much that worked, the function in the model must be STATIC as you said.